# SQL query adding where related to sub query

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, where-clause

Trying to get a where statement on a sub query result. The below works as I want it to, with the exception of **AND low_36 != NULL**. I need this to stop results where the output of low_36 is NULL.

```
SELECT offers.*, 
(SELECT ROUND( MIN( price ) ,2) FROM o_prices WHERE o_id = offers.id AND months = 23 ) AS low_24, 
(SELECT ROUND( MIN( price ) ,2) FROM o_prices WHERE o_id = offers.id AND months = 35 ) AS low_36
(SELECT ROUND( MIN( price ) ,2) FROM o_prices WHERE o_id = offers.id AND months = 47 ) AS low_48 
FROM offers 
LEFT JOIN m_v ON v_v.code = offers.code 
LEFT JOIN m_f_t ON v.f_t_id = m_f_t.id 
LEFT JOIN m_t_t ON v.t_t_id = m_t_t.id 
WHERE status = 1 
AND low_36 != NULL 
LIMIT 2 OFFSET 0
```

I know you can not use results from subqueries in the main where statement, but this is the closest I have come to the correct result. Thank you for any feedback

Comment: Query is not well formed, there is no comma after the second "AS low_36", there is no table alias "v" or "v_v".

Answer (score 0):

Quick way would be

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (SELECT offers.*, 
    (SELECT ROUND( MIN( price ) ,2) FROM o_prices WHERE o_id = offers.id AND months = 23 ) AS low_24, 
    (SELECT ROUND( MIN( price ) ,2) FROM o_prices WHERE o_id = offers.id AND months = 35 ) AS low_36
    (SELECT ROUND( MIN( price ) ,2) FROM o_prices WHERE o_id = offers.id AND months = 47 ) AS low_48 
    FROM offers 
    LEFT JOIN m_v ON v_v.code = offers.code 
    LEFT JOIN m_f_t ON v.f_t_id = m_f_t.id 
    LEFT JOIN m_t_t ON v.t_t_id = m_t_t.id 
    WHERE status = 1) a
WHERE low_36 IS NOT NULL 
LIMIT 2 OFFSET 0
```

Comment: Please don't use arithmetic comparison to NULL, never a good idea.

Comment: @anand sorry I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you want to exclude null values in the subquery itself, thereby avoiding nullifying your aggregate value. Try this:

```
SELECT offers.*, 
(SELECT ROUND( MIN( price ) ,2) FROM o_prices WHERE o_id = offers.id AND months = 23 ) AS low_24, 
(SELECT ROUND( MIN( price ) ,2) FROM o_prices WHERE o_id = offers.id AND months = 35 and price is not null) AS low_36,
(SELECT ROUND( MIN( price ) ,2) FROM o_prices WHERE o_id = offers.id AND months = 47 ) AS low_48 
FROM offers 
LEFT JOIN m_v ON m_v.code = offers.code 
LEFT JOIN m_f_t ON m_v.f_t_id = m_f_t.id 
LEFT JOIN m_t_t ON m_f_t.t_t_id = m_t_t.id 
WHERE status = 1 
LIMIT 2 OFFSET 0
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but this still doesn't remove the result from the list if low_36 returns null.

Comment: @Paul It might be null if ```o_id``` does not return any results for ```offers.id``` in which case, refer to @SQLChao solution above and do a sub-select as he has shown. You can do that in addition to removing nulls from the subquery.